# Backtracing the longest palindromic subsequence

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I modified the code from [Geeks for Geeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-12-longest-palindromic-subsequence/) to backtrace the actual subsequence, not only its length. But when I backtrace and get to the end where I can put an arbitrary character to the middle of the palindrome, I find my solution to be sloppy and not 'Pythonic'. Can someone please help me?

This piece smells particularly bad(if it works correctly at all):

```
if length_matrix[start][end] == 1 and substr_length >= 0:
    middle = sequence[start]
```

Here is the forward pass:

```
def calc_subsequence_lengths(sequence):
    n = len(sequence)

    # Create a table to store results of subproblems
    palindrome_lengths = np.zeros((n, n))

    # Strings of length 1 are palindrome of length 1
    np.fill_diagonal(palindrome_lengths, 1)

    for substr_length in range(2, n + 1):
        for i in range(n - substr_length + 1):
            j = i + substr_length - 1
            if sequence[i] == sequence[j] and substr_length == 2:
                palindrome_lengths[i][j] = 2
            elif sequence[i] == sequence[j]:
                palindrome_lengths[i][j] = palindrome_lengths[i + 1][j - 1] + 2
            else:
                palindrome_lengths[i][j] = max(palindrome_lengths[i][j - 1], 
                                               palindrome_lengths[i + 1][j])
    return palindrome_lengths
```

And here is the traceback:

```
def restore_palindrome(length_matrix, sequence):
    palindrome_left = ''
    middle = ''
    n, n = np.shape(length_matrix)
    # start in the north-eastern corner of the matrix
    substr_length, end = n - 1, n-1
    # traceback
    while substr_length > 0 and end > 1:
        start = end - substr_length
        # if possible, go left
        if length_matrix[start][end] == (length_matrix[start][end - 1]):
            substr_length -= 1
            end -= 1
        # the left cell == current - 2, but the lower is the same as current, go down
        elif length_matrix[start][end] == (length_matrix[start + 1][end]):
            substr_length -= 1
        # both left and lower == current - 2, go south-west
        else:
            palindrome_left += sequence[start]
            substr_length -= 2
            end -= 1
    if length_matrix[start][end] == 1 and substr_length >= 0:
        middle = sequence[start+1]
    result = ''.join(palindrome_left) + middle + ''.join(palindrome_left[::-1])
    return result, int(length_matrix[0][n-1])
```

### **Update**

First off, the problem is to calculate the longest **non-contiguous** palindromic sequence (as stated in the article I referred to). For the sequence `BBABCBCAB`, the output should be `BABCBAB`
Secondly, as I have pointed out, I'm building upon an existing DP solution which works in O(N^2) time and space. It calculates the length just fine, so I need to backtrace the actual palindrome in the most elegant way, not sacrificing efficiency for elegance.

---

Comment: In short, do you want the most pythonic way of finding the longest palindromic subsequence of a string?

Comment: yes, but preferably built upon DP solution